# $stateParams field is undefined if not located within its corresponding ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying for a parent state/view to access a child state/view. I am looking for a workaround.

My state provider configuration is as follows:

```
.state('advertisement', {
    url: '/advertisement', abstract: true, parent: 'authenticated'
})
.state('advertisement.new', {
    url: '/new',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        '@': {
            controller: 'AdvertisementSaveCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'advertisement/views/advertisement.form.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('advertisement.new.field', {
    url: '/:fieldId',
    views: {
        '@advertisement.new': {
            templateUrl: function ($stateParams){
                return 'advertisement/views/fields/advertisement.' + $stateParams.fieldId + '.html';
            }
        }
    }
})
```

In my markup:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active" ng-class="{'active': isActive()}"><!-- not in scope! -->
<div ui-view></div><!-- this is the view targeted by advertisement.new.field -->
```

The `advertisement.new.field` state changes according to the current field (`:fieldId`). I have set up a number of links (located **outside** of my nested `ui-view`) that change the state by changing the `:fieldId` state param but obviously, the `$stateParam.fieldId` is undefined if it is not within the corresponding `ui-view` div.

To put it differently, it seems the isActive method has no access `to $stateParam.fieldId`...

Can anyone please provide a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code samples I don't see in which controller the `isActive()` method is defined. But it must be defined in a controller.

I assume the `isActive()` function is defined on a controller named `MainController`. 
You can then inject the `$state` service in this controller and via the [`$state.params`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#properties_params) you can access the parameters of the active state even outside of the `<ui-view>` tag:

```
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $state) {
      console.log($stateParams);

      this.isActive = function() {
          // access params of active state via $state.params
          console.log($state.params.fieldId);
      };
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Spot on. It works. I was positive it would not work. But then what is the difference between: `$state.params` and `$stateParams`?